# Rubyで書かれたこのコードについて教えて下さい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[ActiveSupport::Concern と、Module#concerning](http://qiita.com/kasei-san/items/c016c626836da09a5a70)
↑こちらの記事から引用しています。

```
module Human
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :name
    def self.default_name
      "太郎"
    end

    def default_name?
      name == self.class.default_name
    end
  end
end
```

この中の`self.class.default_name`という記述がありますが、`self.default_name`というように`class`を省略することはそもそもできないのでしょうか。
できた場合、挙動の違いなどありましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`default_name` はインスタンスメソッドではなく、クラスメソッドである事を理解下さい。
つまり参照する方法は

```
m = Member.new
p m.default_name
```

ではなく

```
p Member.default_name
```

です。これは `default_name` がインスタンス毎に変わる値ではなく、`Member` の普遍的な値にしたいからです。かたや `default_name?` はインスタンスメソッドです。`name` の値を更新する度に戻り値が変わりうる物です。

```
def default_name?
    ...
end
```

ここで比較したい値は、インスタンスのメンバ属性 `name` と、先ほどの普遍的な値 `default_name` なので

```
def default_name?
  name == Member.default_name
end
```

こう書く事が出来ます。ですが出来れば汎用的に書きたいですよね。結果として

```
def default_name?
  name == self.class.default_name
end
```

こう書く事になります。